# Workflow action not executed in Jira Issue Updater plugin

Tags: jenkins, jira, jenkins-plugins, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

So currently I am trying to progress my JIRA workflow with the Jira Issue Updater plugin in Jenkins. Attached are my config screenshot and my workflow. However i get this error when I execute a commit triggered build.

### JIRA Update Results Recorder

Unable to connect to REST service
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://*******:9055/rest/api/2/search?jqlFinished: SUCCESS

This does not have any effect on my Jira workflow.

Thanks for the help in advance and let me know if more information is needed.
Hadi

EDIT: I got a 404 meaning the JQL is incorrect, but when I try to use that in incognito mode I get an empty string, However, if i am locally logged in, I get all issues in xml format.

[Workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5s779.png)
[Jenkins Jira Config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8atP.png)

Comment: The two pictures are identical.

Comment: Both pictures are correctly uploaded now. Thanks @il_rafa

Comment: Looking at the configuration picture, the REST Base URL looks wrong. Can you change it to remove the "/issue/" from the end of the URL. It should end in ".../rest/api/2"

Comment: Yeah I changed it with no effect. Updated picture is uploaded.

Comment: @IanSparkes I feel it is an authentication issue because it get this: {"startAt":0,"maxResults":50,"total":0,"issues":[]} in incognito mode and a complete issues table if im signed in.

Comment: You have access to projects and issues with your userid, so if you are not logged in you w'ont receive issues. If you are logged in you will receive only the issues you are able to access. It may be possible that your jenkins user has no right to view these issues. You may try to give him access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the JIRA plugin instead.
I used Progress JIRA Issues by workflow action step after build successful phase. 
Attaching a screenshot of the configuration.

I am still trying to figure how to pull the issue number from the commit message for this action.

[JIRA PLUGIN CONFIG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xouBI.png)

This is a following question and answer if anybody else gets stuck:

[How can I get JIRA issue number from a commit message in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34144116/how-can-i-get-jira-issue-number-from-a-commit-message-in-jenkins?noredirect=1#comment56065124_34144116)