# How can I get JIRA issue number from a commit message in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jira, jenkins-plugins

I am using Gitlab for our source code management, jenkins for CI jobs and JIRA for issue tracking.

Once I commit in gitlab with an issue number for example "Project-123 edited demo file.", I have a jenkins hook that triggers a build.
I have the JENKINS's Jira Plugin and use Progress JIRA issues by workflow action.
I have a two part question:

1. my JQL for searching for the issue is: `project=PROJ and status="Build Started" and updated >= "-15m"`
   My workflow action is Jenkins Build is Successful.
   However, if i have multiple builds running, when the first build completes successfully it will transition both the issues to BUILD SUCCESSFUL no matter how the second build ends. 
   I want a way I can populate $ISSUE_ID using the commit message in jenkins's SCM change for the jira plugin so I can specify the issue to transition.
2. Progress the worflow a different way if the build fails.

Comment: I don't get it (yet). I don't think it is JIRA related, so if the Jenkins plugin does not allow it, you are stuck. I don't think it is a good idea to transition the workflow by a successful (or failed) build. Normally, the people work with more than one commit on a ticket, so they have to make it explicit when they have finished work.

Comment: @mliebelt we have a workflow that looks like this in JIRA:
“In Progress”
“In Review”
“Build Started”
“Build Successful”
“Deployed to Dev”
“Deployed to Test”
“Done”
 so once the developer is done with his branch, he submits a merge request to the developer, who on approving triggers the ticket from "In Review" to "Build Started" that also triggers a jenkins build. So it is true that the developer might have multiple commits but only his last commit will mention the issue number so that JIRA is updated once for it. 
please let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a work around. Here is how I solved each:
1- I wrote a shell script that took the changes by requesting the api for the build. Then I wrote a regex to take out the issue key from the commit message. I took out only the first reference of an issue. The I used the envinject plugin in jenkins to inject the issue id as a build property to be used later on by the JIRA plugin's progress issue by workflow action step.
Here is the shell script.

```html
xmlfile=$(curl -s "http://*********:8080/jenkins/job/***/${BUILD_NUMBER}/api/xml?wrapper=changes&xpath=//changeSet//comment")
re="PRJ-([0-9])*"
if [[ $xmlfile =~ $re ]];
  then issueKey=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
fi
re2="([0-9])+"
if [[ $issueKey =~ $re2 ]];
  then echo ISSUE_ID=${BASH_REMATCH[0]} > env.properties
fi
```

in the jira pugin I used issueKey=PRJ-$ISSUE_ID as my jql with the status.

2- For this part, I used the [TriggerParametrizedBuild](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) plugin and started a build if the current build failed or was unstable. This new build only progressed the workflow back to "In Progress"