# How to invoke shell script to grab Jira issue number from a commit message to advance a particular ticket to advance to the desired workflow

Tags: shell, jira, jira-plugin

I have a similar situation than [mliebelt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2603665/mliebelt) whereas I need to advance a particular Jira issue ticket to another stage in its worfklow, based on the Issue ID used in it's commit message, by using the Jira Plugin and the "Progress JIRA issues by workflow" action.

I am trying to invoke [Hadi Tabani's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5600832/hadi-tabani) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34181901/6195194) into my Jenkins job but I can't get it working in my situation.

Here is the shell script I am running in my job:

```
 xmlfile=$(curl -s "http://192.168.156.2:8080/job/TEST_PROJECT/${BUILD_NUMBER}/api/xml?wrapper=changes&xpath=//changeSet//comment")
re="TEST-([0-9])*"
if [[ $xmlfile =~ $re ]];
  then issueKey=${BASH_REMATCH[0]}
fi
re2="([0-9])+"
if [[ $issueKey =~ $re2 ]];
  then echo ISSUE_ID=${BASH_REMATCH[0]} > env.properties
fi
```

And here is the console error that gets outputed from the Jenkins console. Any ideas?

```
Started by user Test User
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/TEST_PROJECT
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url ssh://192.168.156.2/opt/git/TEST_PROJECT.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://192.168.156.2/opt/git/TEST_PROJECT.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials jenkins_git_plugin_openssh_private_key
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress ssh://192.168.156.2/opt/git/TEST_PROJECT.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/development^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/development^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision f21ae0a0c612b9e9ecbcf213a113213efba6657f (refs/remotes/origin/development)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f f21ae0a0c612b9e9ecbcf213a113213efba6657f
 > git rev-list 2e550f0f99d231451e03d6c49fd0b6f23cba6953 # timeout=10
[TEST_PROJECT] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson3294487698607557223.sh
+ javac HelloWorld.java
[TEST_PROJECT] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson6212970969648351737.sh
+ curl -s http://192.168.156.2:8080/job/TEST_PROJECT/96/api/xml?wrapper=changes&xpath=//changeSet//comment
+ xmlfile=<changes><comment>TEST-8 starting Jenkins Build
</comment></changes>
+ re=TEST-([0-9])*
+ [[ <changes><comment>TEST-8 starting Jenkins Build </comment></changes> =~ TEST-([0-9])* ]]
/tmp/hudson6212970969648351737.sh: 4: /tmp/hudson6212970969648351737.sh: [[: not found
+ re2=([0-9])+
+ [[ =~ ([0-9])+ ]]
/tmp/hudson6212970969648351737.sh: 8: /tmp/hudson6212970969648351737.sh: [[: not found
[EnvInject] - Injecting environment variables from a build step.
[EnvInject] - [ERROR] - The given properties file path 'env.properties' doesn't exist.
[EnvInject] - [ERROR] - Missing file path was resolved from pattern 'env.properties' .
[EnvInject] - [ERROR] - [EnvInject] - [ERROR] - Problems occurs on injecting env vars as a build step: java.io.IOException: The given properties file path 'env.properties' doesn't exist.
Build step 'Inject environment variables' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Inject environment variables' marked build as failure
Updating TEST-8
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: did you check your code on http://shellcheck.net ? Good luck.

Comment: `/bin/sh` in the output is your clue. Stick `#!/bin/sh` on the top of your script and throw it against http://www.shellcheck.net as shelter suggests and you'll see the issue.